# noSuchMethodError during a called method that exists javaEE

Tags: java, security

i have the following piece of code :

```
private Long getThirdPartyGroupID(Principal principal){
    if(principal instanceof WikiRePrincipal)
        return ((WikiRePrincipal)principal).getThirdPartyGroupID();
....
}
```

Where Principal comes from java.security. 
WikiRePrincipal extends SimplePrincipal and there is te implementation of the method:

```
public Long getThirdPartyGroupID() {
    return thirdPartyGroupID;
}
```

I think it is not a problem caused by this java classes, but i don't know why it throws noSuchMethodError.

Here is the log trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     it.antlia.security.login.WikiRePrincipal.getThirdPartyGroupID()Ljava/lang/Long;
at it.antlia.common.session.UserManager.getThirdPartyGroupID(UserManager.java:3430) [CommonEjb.jar:]
at it.antlia.common.session.UserManager.checkUser(UserManager.java:3463) [CommonEjb.jar:]
```

...........

What could be the problem ?

Comment: can i refresh/rebuild the project in your IDE and say if the error is still present

Comment: This most likely means you are running the code with a different version of the class files than what you compiled it with; or that your class files are not up-to-date with your source files. Re-compile all your code, and make sure that everything is in sync.

Comment: I am Re-compiling all projects 
To know if it works I have to wait that another agency tries the call to our webservices, we don't have a system to test it by ourself !!!!! (I am new in this platform) 
I'll notice when there will be news

Comment: Bad notices 
There is the same problem 
At this point I don't know what it could be .. 
What can I try to look for ?